# Como adicionar links em um 'select' e mudar a largura da caixa 'select' antes do click

Tags: html, css

Tentei adicionar uma referencia de um link em um item de uma lista 'select' "number 2" e não foi possível, que solução devo aderir para linkar esse item?? e também não esta sendo possível aumentar a largura da caixa 'select' antes do click, ?

```css
option:hover{ background-color: #ff0; }
select option{ width: 200px; }
```

```html
<form>

<select id="ctg" class="dt" name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
             
             <option value="1"> number 1</option>
             <option value="2"> <a href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5005/5372580945_2988198c90.jpg">number 2</a></option>
             <option value="3"> number 3</option>
             <option value="4"> number 4</option>
             <option value="5"> number 5</option>
             <option value="6"> number 6</option>
             <option value="7"> number 7</option>
             <option value="8"> number 8</option>
             <option value="9"> number 9</option>
             
           </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode usar tags em textos de `option`s. Primeiro, para aumentar a altura do `select`, você pode usar `onmouseover` em vez de `onmousedown`, para que a caixa aumente antes do clique. E `onmouseleave` em vez de `onblur` para voltar ao normal.

Segundo, você pode colocar a URL no `value` da `option` e no `onchange` redirecionar com `location.href` pegando o respectivo valor da `option` selecionada:

```css
option:hover{ background-color: #ff0; }
select option{ width: 200px; }
```

```html
<form>
  Selecione "number 2":
  <br>
   <select id="ctg" class="dt" name="select1" onmouseover="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='location.href=this.value' onmouseleave="this.size=0;">
                
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 1</option>
      <option value="https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5005/5372580945_2988198c90.jpg">number 2</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 3</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 4</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 5</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 6</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 7</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 8</option>
      <option value="URL_aqui"> number 9</option>
   
   </select>
</form>
```